# Inflate exception when trying to inflate custom layout with Iconify using Robolectric RuntimeEnvironment

Tags: android, robolectric

I have this layout test, in my layout `menu_item_layout.xml` there is an `IconTextView` with text `"{fa-times}"`. When I try to run the test I get `android.view.InflateException`.
But if I remove the text `"{fa-times}"` from `IconTextView`, the test passed successfully.

#### MenuItemTest.kt

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)
class MenuItemLayoutTest {

    @Test
    fun shouldDisplayCorrectTextViews() {
        val layout = RoboLayoutInflater.from(RuntimeEnvironment.application)
                                       .inflate(R.layout.menu_item_layout, MenuItemLayout(RuntimeEnvironment.application, null), true) as MenuItemLayout

        assertEquals(layout.itemNameTextView.text,"Item 001")
    }
}
```

#### menu_item_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

    <com.joanzapata.iconify.widget.IconButton
        android:id="@+id/minusButton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="{fa-minus-circle}"
        android:textColor="@color/minus_button"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My assumption is that the `RuntimeEnvironment.application` needs to call `Iconify.with(FontAwesomeModule())` to load. But I have no clue how to do that. Is it possible to extend `RuntimeEnvironment.application` of `Robolectric`?

I'm using `robolectric:3.1.2`

#### Notes

The test failed when I run `./gradlew test`, but if I run a test on a single file (right clicking the file `MenuItemTest.kt` and `Run`) it passed.

Comment: @mohammadrezakhalifeh I've added the layout.xml file to the question.

Comment: when the text is empty or any other string like `hello`, it is working fine, But when the text is `{fa-...}` it failed with exception `android.view.InflateException`.
I have tried to add the string `{fa-times}` to `string.xml` and it failed as well.

Comment: I'm trying to render external font, FontAwesome, from this library https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-iconify
Using any other characters in `IconTextView` works fine. but when it tries to render the font from FontAwesome it is just not working. I think it has something to do with `RoboRuntimeEnvironment.application`